# Can't get browserify to work, gives Reference Error

Tags: node.js, browserify, bitcore

I'm trying to build bitcore so that t works in the browser. These are the commands I ran:

```
npm install bitcore
```

The I made a file called index.js:

```
var Address = require('bitcore/lib/address');
var Block = require('bitcore/lib/block');
var BlockHeader = require('bitcore/lib/blockheader');
var HDPrivateKey = require('bitcore/lib/hdprivatekey');
var HDPublicKey = require('bitcore/lib/hdpublickey');
var PaymentProtocol = require('bitcore/lib/paymentprotocol');
var PrivateKey = require('bitcore/lib/privatekey');
var PublicKey = require('bitcore/lib/publickey');
var Script = require('bitcore/lib/script');
var Transaction = require('bitcore/lib/transaction');
var URI = require('bitcore/lib/uri');
var Unit = require('bitcore/lib/unit');
```

(this taken straight from the bitcore docs: http://bitcore.io/guide/browser.html)

then I ran this command:

```
browserify index.js -o bitcore-browser.js
```

It seemed to work. Here is the first few lines of the output file:

```
(function e(t,n,r){function s(o,u){if(!n[o]){if(!t[o]){var a=typeof require=="function"&&require;if(!u&&a)return a(o,!0);if(i)return i(o,!0);var f=new Error("Cannot find module '"+o+"'");throw f.code="MODULE_NOT_FOUND",f}var l=n[o]={exports:{}};t[o][0].call(l.exports,function(e){var n=t[o][1][e];return s(n?n:e)},l,l.exports,e,t,n,r)}return n[o].exports}var i=typeof require=="function"&&require;for(var o=0;o<r.length;o++)s(r[o]);return s})({1:[function(require,module,exports){
var Address = require('bitcore/lib/address');
var Block = require('bitcore/lib/block');
var BlockHeader = require('bitcore/lib/blockheader');
var HDPrivateKey = require('bitcore/lib/hdprivatekey');
var HDPublicKey = require('bitcore/lib/hdpublickey');
var PaymentProtocol = require('bitcore/lib/paymentprotocol');
var PrivateKey = require('bitcore/lib/privatekey');
var PublicKey = require('bitcore/lib/publickey');
var Script = require('bitcore/lib/script');
var Transaction = require('bitcore/lib/transaction');
var URI = require('bitcore/lib/uri');
var Unit = require('bitcore/lib/unit');

},{"bitcore/lib/address":2,"bitcore/lib/block":3,"bitcore/lib/blockheader":4,"bitcore/lib/hdprivatekey":18,"bitcore/lib/hdpublickey":19,"bitcore/lib/paymentprotocol":24,"bitcore/lib/privatekey":28,"bitcore/lib/publickey":29,"bitcore/lib/script":30,"bitcore/lib/transaction":33,"bitcore/lib/unit":42,"bitcore/lib/uri":43}],2:[function(require,module,exports){
(function (Buffer){
'use strict';
```

(which i assume means it worked correctly. The file is about 2MB.)

When I add the file to a page, none of the object are there:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="bitcore.browser.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            var p = new PrivateKey(); // ReferenceError: PrivateKey is not defined
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

I even tried to run "uglify" but that had no effect.

Comment: The vars are not defined on the global scope.  You'd need to drop the `var`s or use `global.PrivateKey = require('...')`, if you really wanted to litter the global scope with all your requires.

Comment: @numbers1311407 that code is taken directly from the bitcore documentation page: http://bitcore.io/guide/browser.html their docs is wrong?

Comment: No, the example just shows how you'd require the modules, to then be used in the same file/scope. The intention is not to globally define variables to use later in other files or inline on the page.

Comment: You can alternatively expose `require` for certain modules and allow the modules to be required outside the bundle instead of defining them globally.  Take a look at the docs for [external requires](https://github.com/substack/node-browserify#external-requires)